# Highchart: can I make sure the values on the Y axis are only integers?

Tags: highcharts

I am new to Highchart.

I have a line chart. X axis is a series of dates, and the Y values are only integers.

How can I make Highchart display only integers on the values of Y axis?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to null all values in xAxis or use following code.

```
xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
```

Please see the example 
http://jsfiddle.net/ssgoanb5/

See the Doc: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.enabled

**New Updates:**

For avoiding decimals values on graph Axis(x/y), Add allowDecimals attributes.

See the Doc. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.allowDecimals

```
yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    }
```

Please check the updated JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ssgoanb5/6/

Comment: Finoy, it seems your solution is not working for me. Two reasons: 1) I need the labels on the x axis. 2) In my case I have zooming. When I zoomed, I see decimals on the Y axis. See this updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/mddc/ssgoanb5/5/

Comment: Please check the updated JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ssgoanb5/6/
Its may solve your problem. also i have updated the answer

Comment: Thanks, Finoy. It is just that simple. I went through highchart docs myself before, but it seems I missed it. Thanks, agains!!!